# Choose Checkbox Insted of radio as a widget in drupal custom content type

Tags: nodes

While adding field in content type I had chosen **Check boxes/radio buttons** as widget.
By default it takes radio button as a widget.
I want check boxes as a widget instead of Radio Button. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit in Field Settings to set Number of Values to Unlimited or more than 1. Then Checkboxes will be used.

Radio buttons are used when user can only select one value.